# html me sale todo el texto en negrita

Tags: html, html5

Estoy empezando con esto del HTML y mi problema es que hago una página web muy sencilla sin  por ningún lado y sin embargo el navegador (firefox y chrome) me lo muestran todo en negrita. Es así porque cuando quiero poner un strong a alguna palabra, no noto ningún cambio, debido a que está ya todo en negrita. Puede ser porque todo está englobado en encabezados, pero he creado un párrafo aparte y me sigue saliendo igual. Adjunto código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Cartelera</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contenedor">
    <h1 id="titulo" style="color:red;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000000"><a href="http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film744699.html">Persiguiendo a Amy</a></h1>
    <h2 id="director">Director: Kevin Smith</h2>
    <h3 id="actor1">Actor principal: Ben Affleck</h3>
    <h4 id="actor2">Actor secundario: Joey Lauren Adams</h4>
    <h4 id="argumento" style="text-align:justify">
    Argumento: Holden y Banky son dibujantes de un cómic independiente de éxito. En una convención conocen a Alyssa, que también lleva su propio cómic. Tras la convención quedan en un par de ocasiones y Holden se enamora de Alyssa. Cuando él cree que ella siente lo mismo por él se da cuenta de que ella es lesbiana. A pesar del golpe emocional y las bromas de su amigo y compañero de trabajo Banky, decide darle una oportunidad como amiga y conocerla mejor.
    </h4>
    <p><strong>beeee</strong></p>
    <h5 id="puntuacion">Puntuación: 8</h5>
    <div id="calificacion" style="color:gray;font-size:10px;text-align:right">Película no recomendada para menores de 18 años</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberias leer mas sobre las etiquetas `h1,h2,h3,etc` ya que por defecto tienen negrita

Comment: Las etiquetas `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, ... normalmente se usan para títulos y subtítulos, por lo cual siempre te mostrará en negrilla. Intenta no abusar del uso de este tag. ;)

Comment: Aquí te dejo un enlace donde te explican como usar las etiquetas HTML, así entenderás mejor cuando usar cada etiqueta https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp, también miraría como funciona `CSS` así podrás dar estilos a tus etiquetas `HTML` https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

los tags h1 .. a h6 colocan el texto en negrita prueba utilizar una tabla o divs para mostrar los datos

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film744699.html">Persiguiendo a Amy</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Director: Kevin Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Actor principal: Ben Affleck</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Actor secundario: Joey Lauren Adams</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia de `<h4>` a un `<p>` el `id="argumento"` y notarás la diferencia.

Ejemplo:

```
<p id="argumento" style="text-align:justify">
    Argumento: Holden y Banky son dibujantes de un cómic independiente de éxito. En una convención conocen a Alyssa, que también lleva su propio cómic. Tras la convención quedan en un par de ocasiones y Holden se enamora de Alyssa. Cuando él cree que ella siente lo mismo por él se da cuenta de que ella es lesbiana. A pesar del golpe emocional y las bromas de su amigo y compañero de trabajo Banky, decide darle una oportunidad como amiga y conocerla mejor.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

El browser por defecto añade la propiedas `font-weight: bold` a las etiquetas de `h1 ... h6`

Lo puedes ver en tu ejemplo:

[image: Font weight]

Puedes agregar una regla que sea `font-weight: normal` y verás como no hay más negritas:

Answer (score -1):

Por ejemplo en el argumento estas usando h4, te recomiendo sustituir esa etiqueta por  y si deseas aplicar estilos label class="miestilo", donde en el fichero css tendrás por ejemplo

```
.miestilo{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Cartelera</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contenedor">
    <h1 id="titulo" style="color:red;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000000"><a href="http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film744699.html">Persiguiendo a Amy</a></h1>
    <h2 id="director">Director: Kevin Smith</h2>
    <h3 id="actor1">Actor principal: Ben Affleck</h3>
    <h4 id="actor2">Actor secundario: Joey Lauren Adams</h4>
    <label id="argumento" style="color:blue; text-align:justify">
    Argumento: Holden y Banky son dibujantes de un cómic independiente de éxito. En una convención conocen a Alyssa, que también lleva su propio cómic. Tras la convención quedan en un par de ocasiones y Holden se enamora de Alyssa. Cuando él cree que ella siente lo mismo por él se da cuenta de que ella es lesbiana. A pesar del golpe emocional y las bromas de su amigo y compañero de trabajo Banky, decide darle una oportunidad como amiga y conocerla mejor.
    </label>
    <p><strong>beeee</strong></p>
    <h5 id="puntuacion">Puntuación: 8</h5>
    <div id="calificacion" style="color:gray;font-size:10px;text-align:right">Película no recomendada para menores de 18 años</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: La respuesta es simple: Esta utilizando etiquetas de titulo que por defecto tienen negrita, lo ideal seria explicarle para que sirven o que utilizar para contenidos. Por lo que respondes, no es una respuesta, sino una sugerencia